# Using Teradata Volatile Table in SSIS ADO NET Source

Tags: volatile

Put simply, can I use an ADO NET Source task to query a Teradata VOLATILE TABLE?  For context, using Teradata SQL Assistant, I can easily create a Teradata VOLATILE TABLE, insert data into it and select data from it.  In Visual Studio, using SSIS SQL Tasks, I am also able to create and insert date into a Teradata VOLATILE TABLE.  However, because the table does not actually exist yet, it appears we cannot use a separate ADO NET Source task to select data from it, meaning we also cannot map the columns.  We get the error "[Teradata Database][3807] Object 'TABLE_NAME' does not exist."  If the data in a VOLATILE TABLE, and more accurately the VOLATILE TABLE column definitions, are only available at run time can an ADO NET Source task be used to query a Teradata VOLATILE TABLE?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Really old, and not sure if it will work. But You can set validation to false, that might do what you are wanting.

Comment: I tried but validation to false did not work in this case.

Comment: What about creating a table in your DB and inserting the data you need into it?